# Problem trying to match a word with a letter with accent mark and with "del". REGEX in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the following three expressions:

```
"Facultad Regional Villa María"
"Facultad Regional Mar del Plata"
"Facultad Regional Haedo"
```

This what i did:

```
"^(Facultad Regional)( [A-Z][a-z]*){1,5}$"
```

As you can see, `Facultad Regional` must be at the beginning of the string.

I can match the third expression perfectly. But not the other two. I need the following concept to put in my regex. I need that if the word "del" exists, is still valid. Also, if a word has an alphabet character with an accent mark, it's also valid.

Thanks in advance. I'm glad to read your answers (:

Comment: `( [A-Z][a-z]*){1,5}$` means _Any english letter or none from 1 to 5 times_. Makes sense that it doesn't match other two expressions

Comment: Have you tried using `\w`?

Comment: If `del` exists anywhere or as one of the 5 words? Current regex isn't looking for `del`. Does having `del` supercede other rule(s)? e.g. `model` and `delta` should be found?

Comment: @thebjorn That would be looser than intended.

Comment: @sudden_appearance Yeah, I know but i don't know how to do it to make it work. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @user3783243 As one of the five words, to be precise. It must be after "Facultad Regional". It can only be found "del". The other words that can be matched if first letter is upper and the rest lower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've said, I got these rules

- String starts with Facultad Regional
- Then there can be from 1 to 5 following words

  - `del`
  - word that is title cased and has no more uppercase letters afterwards

That's the regex you want `^Facultad Regional( \p{Lu}\p{Ll}+| del){1,5}$`

P.S. `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}` means *letter that has upper(lower)case variant of this letter*

UPD: to use `\p` in your regex, you need to use [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library

Comment: I tried it but it gives an error from the re library.  The problem is with the \p.

Comment: @user3783243, it is achievable with [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763162/re-findall-bad-escape-for-category-s-and-p) has an explanation. Briefly: `re` module has pure functionality with unicode regex

Comment: @sudden_appearance Thanks with the regex module works perfectly.

Comment: @sudden_appearance You should add that to the answer